# Lebesgue integration over a set of measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Given a function $f(x)$ and a set $E$ of measure zero. I want to prove that
$$\int_E f(x) dx=0.$$
Intuitively, we have $\int_E f(x) dx \le m(E) \times \sup f(x) = 0\times \sup f(x)$. Since we have no assumption for $f(x)$, can we conclude $0\times \sup f(x)=0?$ If this is not the right direction, how can we prove the integration is zero?

Comment: If $f(x) = \frac 1 x$ and $E = \{ 0 \}$, you are left with $0 \times \infty$, which is an indeterminate form.

Comment: Depending on what you know: approximate $f$ by simple functions, or use the MCT or the DCT.

Comment: @nicomezi $0\times \infty$ usually defined to be $0$ in measure theoretic integration theory.

Comment: Do you have some examples or reference in mind ? @zhw.

Comment: @nicomezi  Rudin, Real and Complex Analysis, Chapter 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have :

$$\left| \int_E f(x) dx \right| \le \int_E |f(x)| dx.$$

Now we consider $g_n(x) = \min \{|f(x)|,n\}$ which is increasing toward $f$.
Then, by monotone convergence theorem : $$\lim_n \int_E g_n(x) dx =\int_E |f(x)| dx$$

and $$\int_E g_n(x) dx \le m(E)n = 0.$$

The wanted equality is thus proven.

Comment: Thanks for your strict derivations. One more comment, because $g_n(x)$ is positive, we can just obtain $\int_E g_n(x) dx =0, \forall n$ from your last equality.

Comment: Indeed you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

I'm definitely not an expert in analysis (let alone measure theory), but I'll take this opportunity to try out this proof.

My idea is to approximate $f$ by a sequence $(f_i)\to f$ such that $f_i \leq f_{i+1}$. I believe this is always possible if you allow these functions to be simple functions. Now consider the sequence

$$ 
\left(\int_Ef_idm\right)
$$

This sequence will $0$ as $i\to\infty$, which leads me to believe that we can conclude that $\int_Efdm=0$ by the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: It is a nice thinking, and you have the similar thought as the other person!

Answer (score 0):

Some answers are using MCT and the like to prove this, but I think this result is almost a matter of definition. (Furthermore, this result may be used in the proof of MCT, so it's possilbe some circular logic might arise.)

Following Rudin (RCA): Suppose $f\ge 0.$ Then by definition

$$\tag 1 \int_E f = \sup \int_E s,$$

where the supremum is taken over all simple functions $s$ such that $0\le s \le f.$ Now for any such $s=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k\chi_{A_k},$ we have by definition

$$\tag 2 \int_E s = \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k m(E\cap A_k).$$

If $m(E)=0,$ then each $m(E\cap A_k)=0,$ hence $(2) =0.$ Therefore $m(E)=0$ implies $(1)$ is $0.$